# What is the difference between \e[38;5;175m and \[\e[38;5;175m\] as it relates to bash colors?

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I have been trying to learn how to customize my shell and I came across two different ways of specifying colors in the Bash shell. They both seem to accomplish the same goal and I am not sure what (if any) is the difference. What do the surrounding [ and ] do?.

Example:

```
# colors!
red="\e[38;5;196m"
lightMagenta="\[\e[38;5;175m\]"
reset="\[\033[0m\]"

# Change command prompt
source ~/git-prompt.sh
export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
export PS1="$lightMagenta\u@\h$green\$(__git_ps1)$red \W $ $reset"
```

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: (Also FYI, `\033` is the same thing as `\e`.)

Comment: BTW, I don't recommend the use of terminal-specific codes in literals - use the `tput` program to generate the right ones for the terminal you're using, so you don't get loads of mess when your assumptions turn out wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a page about [Bash Prompt customization](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash/Prompt_customization) that says:

> Wrapping [terminal escape sequences] in `\[` `\]` is recommended by the Bash man page. This helps Bash ignore non-printable characters so that it correctly calculates the size of the prompt.

Comment: Thank you! This is a very old post, so apologies for taking so long to accept this answer! :)